# Access PDF.js Viewer functions / events

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, pdf.js

I am looking into putting together a small site that reads a few PDF files and loads them in the [PDF.js viewer](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/web). (I want to use the viewer specifically) I still want all of the viewer UI and functionality present, just adding a sidebar with a list of files to chose from.

Alas I have not been able to really understand the PDF.js code (or a lot of the Viewer.js code provided for that matter)

*Currently I am looking for a way to pass the PDF.js viewer a new file to open.* (Without reloading the page and using the url parameter)

With that said that is only the bare minimum functionality to continue with this project.

I am also looking for something that can resemble a function reference for any of the Viewer / PDF.js functions that can be used for interactions:

1. I/O of the files
2. moving through pages / headings
3. scaling the pdf
4. any event triggers

I haven't been able to find anything direct from [Mozzila's Github Wiki](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki). And the recent tutorials that I have been able to find don't make use of the Viewer at all.

Comment: Sounds like you missed https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#wiki-gh-pages and https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#wiki-file

Comment: As mentioned in the post though I would rather not do this via a the URL parameter and instead just pass it the new file in javascript directly. I am using the fully compiled site version as well, but still don't have any idea on how to access any of the JS functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open a file from a url:

```
PDFView.open(url, 0);
```

Set page:

```
PDFView.page = 2;
```

zoom/scale:

```
PDFView.zoomIn(10);
PDFView.zoomOut(10);
```

Basically just look at the PDFView object in viewer.js.