# How to trigger search functionality of google chrome browser using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In Google Chrome, I want to trigger the browser's 'find' functionality from Javascript. I tried the following which does not work.

```
window.find("sometext")
```

How can I do this? Is this possible?

Note that simple 'DOM' search is not possible, because I have an iframe with an embedded PDF inside. The <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in chrome searches the DOM on the page and any PDF inside of it.

Comment: Assuming that your text is somewhere that;s displayed on a page, then probably a good way to start is to understand what the DOM is.

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find (note the really big red box at the top)

Comment: *"I want to trigger the browser's 'find' functionality from Javascript"* you mean, the thing you get with CTRL+F? try `alert('Please press CTRL+F')`. Otherwise, it can't be done.

Comment: That is correct. I do not want to hit CTRL+F. I want to hit a button that triggers the find box to come up, OR execute the same functionality as that passing text into it.

Comment: @NoelB, this text could be in an iframe or a PDF inside of an iframe.

Comment: maybe a jQuery.grep of document.body.innerHTML

Comment: @Rolando I see.  Maybe you can use this as a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987478/pdf-js-using-search-function-on-embedded-pdf

Comment: @Kevin B That is exactly what I want to do. I saw a window.find in some post, but it does not work in Chrome.. looking for something simple like that for the current version of Chrome. If it's not possible, it's not possible, but it seems like it would be very useful.